# Google Org Chart Zoom In and Zoom Out

Tags: jquery, zooming, google-visualization

I'm using [Google Org Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) in my Project. I go through the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#events)  for `Zoom In` and `Zoom Out` Method. But I did not see anything related to it.

I have attached the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L23h37pd/) with sample data.

I tried with following code:

```
var options = {
      explorer: {
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 4.0
        },
 };
```

But still no luck. Is there any other way to achieve this? Thank You.